# Where to locate unit tests for Angular source code?

Tags: angular

I'm currently reading Angular source code to gain a better understanding of how some of its parts work. I want to read its corresponding unit tests but could not find its locations? Can anyone give me a heads up? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For each component, there is a file with the name of that component **component.spec.ts**. You can use this file to write the test cases.